# Allow only one space between letters

Tags: php, regex

I don't know almost anything about regex, but I need to allow only one space between letters, this is what I have done with another questiona and answer, plus random tries with regex101:

```
/^(\d){1,}(\:[A-Za-z0-9-]+([ a-zA-Z0-9-]+)?)?\:(\d){1,}(?:\.(\d){1,2})?$/m
```

The fomat should be:

```
[integer]:[optional label :][integer/decimal]
```

Example:

```
12:aaa:12.31
56:a s f:15
34:45.8
```

I have done some random tries without any success,I'm only able to allow infinite space, could someone help me? I have also looked at others answers, but I couldn't implement in my regex.

Check if error:

```
    preg_match_all('/^(\d+)(:[A-Z0-9-]+(?: [A-Z0-9-]+)*)?:(\d+(?:\.\d{1,2})?)$/mi', $_POST['ratetable'], $out);
    if($out[0]!=explode("\n",$_POST['ratetable'])){
        header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
        echo json_encode(array(0=>'Invalid price table at line: '.implode(", ", array_diff_key(array_flip(explode("\n",$_POST['ratetable'])),array_flip($out[0])))));
        exit();
    }
```

Comment: A label can be `a s f` including spaces? So anything without `:`? So `[^:]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make the regex a bit shorter and allow a single space in between each letter like this:

```
/^(\d+)(:[A-Z0-9-]+(?: [A-Z0-9-]+)*)?:(\d+(?:\.\d{1,2})?)$/gmi
```

[regex101 demo](http://regex101.com/r/lW0oX4)

If you want to capture only the label (and exclude the `:`) in the capture, you can use [this one](http://regex101.com/r/tB7gV7).

Comment: Could you take also a look at the code that I use to check if there is any error and return the line/s? It works, but I think it isn't so efficient

Comment: @Dheed Hmm, I'm not very good at PHP, but do you really need the 'g' flag if you use `preg_match_all`? And are you going to use the numbers and labels? You can make some of the captures non-capture groups if you don't need them (i.e. `( ... )` becomes `(?: ... )`) That would make things faster. Otherwise, your code seems fine to me.

Answer (score 2):

I think

```
^\d+:([^:]+:)?\d+(\.\d+)?$
```

might do it...

It means: `<int> + ":" + [label + ":"] + <float>` where `label` can be anything but `:`.

Comment: it matches more than one spaces between letters

Comment: @revo Yes it matches everything between `:`. I sort of skipped the question part and just made a pretty regex =)

Answer (score 1):

You're nearly there:

```
(?: [a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*
```

the above would mean: space followed by at least one in the character group; the latter group any number of times, without capturing

Comment: how about `12:aa[three spaces here]a:13`

Comment: @revo: replacing `([ a-zA-Z0-9-]+)?` with `(?: [a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*` in the original regex rejects `aa[three spaces here]a` exactly as expected, because of the `[a-zA-Z0-9-]+` part...

Answer (score 1):

You can use [preg_match](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php)

```
$str = 'Another Example String 1_2-3';
echo $str . "<br />\n";
if (preg_match('#^(?:[\w-]+ ?)+$#', $str)){
    echo 'Legal format!';
} else {
    echo 'Illegal format!';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
^\d+:([\w\d]+ ?)*:?\d+(\.\d+)?$
```

[Live demo](http://regex101.com/r/sW5vW8)